# Unable to connect to MYSQL using Visual Studio 2019 Server Explorer

Tags: mysql, .net, visual-studio, ado.net

I am working with Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. When I go to Tools > Connect to Database... menu option, I do not see MySQL server. What do I need to do in order to see MySQL server?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select **Microsoft SQL Server** instead of **Microsoft Access Database File**.